# Service on server

Tags: java, web-services, heroku, jersey, jax-rs

I am deploying restful service on heroku. On my local machine I used a URL like `http://localhost:8080/*` to query data from database(that's what service is implemented for)... now I am deploying app as WAR on Heroku. It's generating domain name like myapp.heroku.com.

What changes do I need to make in my code(for URL) to deploy it on server...means will it be something like `http://myapp.heroku.com/`*, do I
 need to mention port number?

Comment: Very unclear what you're asking. What kind of database did you have at :8080 and is the same database running in heroku anywhere? Or what is the service and what uses the url?

Comment: @zapl I am using service call(service is implemented in same project) to get data, locally i will use localhost:8080 , but what will be url in place of localhost:8080, when it is deployed on heroku?

Comment: yes, those myapp.heroku.com urls should be right when in doubt. No port.